Proof-Theoretic Advantages to Using Only NANDs in Infinitary Logics
This question comes out of a question on Philosophy Stack Exchange, and a particular difference of opinion in regards to the initial question stated in 'Is there any major benefit to using NAND in infinitary logic?'. The question revolves around an open-ended notion of formal or computational efficiency involving the reduction of a plurality of Boolean operators to the functionally complete use of only NAND. To wit:

So then collapsing the representation of one of the two fundamental variables in an infinitary logic as such (the size-of-conjunctions/disjunctions variable) to a NAND-representation: would that make any of the kinds of "reasoning" they do in that sphere ("hyper-reasoning" might be a fairer name for it, if not to fully proclaim it either) more "efficient"? Is NAND-reasoning always somehow more efficient, either perpetually or cumulatively, than having to sort between AND- and OR-reasoning? Or w.r.t. infinitary logic, does the core premise of such systems make them inherently so complex already that it doesn't matter if you tried to "simplify" the nature of the signature by reducing the significance of one of the key variables from two patterns to one?

My response was to reject the increased efficiency based on:

VLSI practices which eschew using NAND only given the optimization by minimizing transistors
CPU instruction set design where the op codes generally don't include the use of NAND preferring to use the richer set of operators and actually excluding NAND on the basis of simplifying the op code/namespace schema
Comparing the length of the formal expressions in an infinitary logical statement using the up arrow in contrast to alternating conjunction-disjunction pairs

But user11867's response was to counter assert that there is indeed a proof-theoretic benefit in mathematical logic of the use in an infinitary logic given a reduction in steps for a proof such that it was claimed:

The usual proof would require that Step 2 be broken into two substeps: first we prove the infinitary conjunction has the property, and then we prove the negation of that conjunction has the property. Using the NAND sentences, we never have to prove the infinitary conjunction has the property. Instead, we get that part for free... I am not sure how important this improvement in efficiency is.

Given the nature of the claim, user11867 offered to substantiate that claim with a proof theoretic example in mathematical logic using LaTeX markup.
So, the question is there a proof-theoretic simplification and complexity advantage to using only NANDs in sentences of an infinitary logic in the language of mathematical logic as maintained by user11867, and if so, what is its nature?
I apologize if this question is a little more conceptual than computational, and would welcome criticisms to preserve the question in the forum if it violates community norms in some way.

@user11867 I'm not a contributor to this forum, so if you can adapt the question in response to your proffered response, go for it.

@KristianBerry If you're interested. I'd be to curious what the math folks have here to offer in terms of mathematical logic and proof theory.

Yeah it's all good, I don't have the right standing on this SE to post new questions anyway. I mean I can try but it always prompts me (because almost all the questions that I did post here before were not high enough quality).

From the passage you quoted, it seems that  user11867 is saying that NAND-related steps are easier to analyze if NAND is primitive. That's true, but AND-and-NOT-related steps are easier to analyze if AND and NOT are primitive. And in my experience, the latter situation arises more often than the former.

The portion of the original question to which I was responding was:

would [using NAND only] make any of the kinds of "reasoning" they do in [infinitary logic] ... more "efficient"?

Because Philosophy Stack Exchange does not support LaTeX, I could not say exactly what I meant in that answer. And so I offered to elaborate if given an opportunity.
First, we must define what it means for a formula to be built using only the NAND operation. We are working with propositional formulas, not predicate formulas, so let $\mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$ denote the set of infinitary propositional formulas. That is, we begin with some nonempty set $PV$ of propositional variables, and we let $\mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$ be the smallest set such that

$PV \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$,
if $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$, then $\neg \varphi \in \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$, and
if $\Phi \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$ is nonempty and countable, then $\bigwedge \Phi \in \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$.

Here, countable means finite or countably infinite. We then let $\mathcal{N} \subseteq \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$ be the smallest set of formulas such that

$PV \subseteq \mathcal{N}$, and
if $\Phi \subseteq \mathcal{N}$ is nonempty and countable, then $\neg \bigwedge \Phi \in \mathcal{N}$.

Then $\mathcal{N}$ is the set of formulas built up using only the NAND operation. It now follows that for all $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$, there exists a $\varphi' \in \mathcal{N}$ such that $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi'$. (That is, $\varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi'$ is a tautology.) To see this, choose $p \in PV$ and note that
$$
\textstyle{\vdash \top \leftrightarrow \neg \bigwedge \{p, \neg \bigwedge \{p\}\}.}
$$
From here, the claim follows by formula induction on $\varphi$, since
\begin{align}
&\textstyle{\vdash \neg \varphi \leftrightarrow \neg \bigwedge \{\varphi, \top\},} \text{ and}\tag{1}\\
&\textstyle{\vdash \bigwedge \Phi \leftrightarrow \neg \bigwedge \{\neg \bigwedge \Phi, \top\}}.\tag{2}
\end{align}
Now suppose there is some property of formulas, say $\mathcal{E}$, and we wish to prove $\mathcal{E}(\varphi)$ for all $\varphi \in \mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$. Also suppose that $\mathcal{E}(\varphi')$ and $\vdash \varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi'$ together imply $\mathcal{E}(\varphi)$. In other words, $\mathcal{E}$ is a property of formulas that is preserved by logical equivalence. Then it suffices to prove that $\mathcal{E}(\varphi')$ holds for all $\varphi' \in \mathcal{N}$. By the above, we can prove this by induction on $\mathcal{N}$, showing that

$\mathcal{E}(p)$ for all $p \in PV$, and
if $\mathcal{E}(\varphi)$ for all $\varphi \in \Phi$, then $\mathcal{E}(\neg \bigwedge \Phi)$.

This is a priori more efficient than proving this by induction on $\mathcal{F}_{\omega_1}$, since that would require us to prove three things:

$\mathcal{E}(p)$ for all $p \in PV$,
if $\mathcal{E}(\varphi)$, then $\mathcal{E}(\neg \varphi)$, and
if $\mathcal{E}(\varphi)$ for all $\varphi \in \Phi$, then $\mathcal{E}(\bigwedge \Phi)$.

However, as I mentioned in my original answer, and as I can see much more clearly now that it is written out, this greater "efficiency" seems to be without any practical benefit. Any proof of $\mathcal{E}(\neg \bigwedge \Phi)$ can be easily converted into a proof of $\mathcal{E}(\neg \varphi)$ and $\mathcal{E}(\bigwedge \Phi)$ by a simple application of (1) and (2).
